# 16 bit Rotate Left and Right for Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have tried to search for circular rotate left and circular rotate right for 16 bits of data (not the 8 bit ones) in Java but most circular rotates I can find handles 8 bits of data. How do I perform 16 bits of circular rotate left and right in Java ? Thanks.

Below are my current codes that do not work:

```
public byte[] rotr(byte[] input, int shift) {
    int output = (binToInt(input) << shift) | (binToInt(input) >> (16 - shift));
    return BigInteger.valueOf(output).toByteArray();
}

public int binToInt(byte[] b) {
    return new BigInteger(b).intValue();
}

public String byteToHex(byte b) {
    char hexDigit[] = {
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
    };
    char[] array = {hexDigit[(b >> 4) & 0x0f], hexDigit[b & 0x0f]};
    return new String(array);
}

public String byteArrayToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        sb.append(byteToHex((byte) bytes[i]));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] out = rotr(new byte[] {(byte) 0x97, (byte) 0xA1}, 7);
    System.out.println(byteArrayToHex(out));
}
```

Hex (0x97A1) bit string: 1001011110100001

After attempted rotr-7: 11001011;

Excepted bit string: 1101000011001011 (0xD0CB)

Comment: Probably take the existing 8-bit code, and extend it.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that fails?

Answer (score 0):

You are really making things hard on yourself by putting data into a byte array. This makes it also hard to tell if your problem is in the conversion or in the rotation.

The rotation itself pretty simple:

```
 public static int ror16(int data, int distance) {
     distance &= 15; // limit rotation to distance mod 16
     data &= 0xFFFF; // ensure only the lower 16 bits can be set
     return (data >> distance) | (data << (16 - distance));
 }
```

Note that when shifting an int (supposedly holding 16 bits) to the right you need to ensure that the upper 16 bits are really zeros, otherwise you will be shifting in garbage.

Your problems most likely stem from the conversion from byte[] to int. The constructor BigInteger(byte[]) will assume that the value is *signed*, thus your BigInteger when converted to int gives you 0xFFFF97A1. That trips up your rotation, since you do not account for the upper bits being set.

Edit: Drop all the byte[] fluff and just use the more sensible int for handling 16 bit values:

```
public static main(String[] argv) {
    int result = ror16(0x97A1, 7) & 0xFFFF;
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(result));
}
```

Comment: Do I need to make any changes to the binToInt() when using your ror16 ?

Comment: Probably a recommendation on how I can convert 16 bits to integers would be nice.

Comment: @thotheolh Why convert at all? You asked how to rotate and you got it basically right, but made your enviroment so complicated you couldn't see where the problems are. Why not get rid of all the conversion fluff and just use int in the first place (and I mean *everywhere*).

Comment: The reason I am trying to convert to int and all that is because I am trying to do operations on 16 bits at a time rather than the conventional byte by byte operation. Using your ror16, how do I do a  16 bits rotate right by 7 (1001011110100001) to (1101000011001011) without using byte[] to contain the input bits and use your integer data input instead ?

Comment: Sorry you lost me. Why do you *put* data in byte[] in the first place when you *don't* want to do operations on the byte level?